# why does only the last row of the listview changes its background color no matter whichever row is clicked in android?

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

I have generated a `Listview`  using   `SimpleAdapter` and I have used `fortysevendegree swiplelistview` library. Here `swipy` is my `listview id`. The problem is that whichever row I click the last row only changes its background to black. I want to change the background color of my selected row only.  My codes are as follows.As I am a newbie please explain me step by step what to do.

mycontacts.java

```
  SimpleAdapter k=new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),val,R.layout.contact2,new String[]{"name","path","id"},new int[]{R.id.example_itemname,R.id.path,R.id.contactid})
    {

        @Override
            public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            { 
     final View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
     final RelativeLayout l=(RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.front);
     final View vh=(View)v.findViewById(R.id.view1);
     final View vv=(View)v.findViewById(R.id.viewvert);
     final View orange=(View)v.findViewById(R.id.vieworange);
     ImageView purple=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
     swipy.setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener(){

@Override
public void onClickFrontView(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    super.onClickFrontView(position);
          l.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
vh.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
vv.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
    orange.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
    name.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"swipe"+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
     return v;
            }
    };
        swipy.setAdapter(k);
```

Comment: What are the changes to be made? Can you please tell me

Comment: I think this happened because you changed all view to final ( I know you need do that because you try use those on onClickFrontView but...), you need use ViewHolder and you need save selected index in the one list to change background,

Comment: can you give me some links for that? As I din get what u mean to say

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html